# How to show week number using Angular material v12

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker, angular12

I am using Angular material datepicker.
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/

Is there is way to show week numbers of this datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.

It's been requested from the Angular Material team but they responded with this:

https://github.com/angular/material/issues/10003#issuecomment-364730323

> We have no plans to add an option to visually display the week number on the calendar as this is not part of the Material Design Spec.

Week numbers would be great feature to add, but won't happen until Google decides to add it to the Material Design Spec.